# How can I get document in the server Alfresco?

Tags: download

I have a trash with my physical server and the `MySQL Bdd`.

The technical team has restoring data `(bdd)` with a shift about System.

I have problem about download some file that contain :

```
Le contenu de l'élément est manquant : 
élément : workspace://SpacesStore/1654e155-5c8c-480a-883a-6768dbf96b7e 
lecteur : ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2016/5/30/11/47/b60f71a2-5d63-483b-a6af-5fc34feb0899.bin, mimetype=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=fr_FR] 
Veuillez contacter votre administrateur système.
```

Do you have any idea for recuperation the good file in the system ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: Excuse me, I looked into base if we could find a référérence from the node, but I found nothing.
I try to find my original file.

Comment: So you had a problem with your installation, and restore has been done, is this correct? You're now missing a complete node, or just the content of the node?